# Excel Formula Delineation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi Overflow Community,

I am currently reviewing a complex financial/operating model and am trying to illustrate how different calculations are made within the excel.

Would anyone know of a way to automatically generate a flowchart/map of the inputs to formulas that delineates their location? E.g. :

value 1 = value 2 (from sheet 2) * value 3 (from sheet 3) 
value 2 = value 4 (from sheet 2) * value 5 (from sheet 2)

etc. etc.

Comment: Do you mean [finding precedents](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-the-relationships-between-formulas-and-cells-a59bef2b-3701-46bf-8ff1-d3518771d507)?

Comment: Yes, but specifically, I was wondering if there was a way to automatically display a map of all precedents because the sheet has a bunch of sheets feeding into each other in succession.

Comment: Maybe look into the Inquire Add-In, which comes pre-installed with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshots refer.

**Summary**

- Automation exists yet suitability depends upon user application(s)/purpose
- Native formula editing options arguably fit the bill RE:

> "*delineates their location*"

- Variants exist albeit some have external software dependencies and are not innate RE: Excel (i.e. may be relatively time-expensive; RE: online solutions: may fall short of desired functionality/aesthetic value not to mention potential IP/confidentiality assurance(s)
- Unaware of custom build automated tools where delineation presented within Excel
- Scope for future contribution plausible - e.g. using 'formulatext' and customised VB code; yet would entail project in its own right

---

**(1) Native**

[image: Native F2 Excel]

As mentioned in initial comments, one can trace precedent/dependent using the appropriate option located within the Formula section of the main ribbon.

[image: Trace dependent(s)/precedent(s)]

*Greater detail req. to establish genuine suitability of this approach*.

---

**(2) Online resources(e.g. [here](https://www.excelformulabeautifier.com/))**

[image: Online formatting tool]

However, as this does little to 'delineate' location it may be of little value/use depending upon intended application.

---

**(3) Custom/manual builds**

[image: Manual depiction]

Unaware of automated tool to create screenshot immediately above.